# Getting list/array of dates for a selected month and year in android

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, date, android-listview

How can we get a list/array of dates for a selected month and year example: August, 2012. So that a user can select a particular date of that month in android. Also what is the efficient way to store date(eg. 01-05-2012) in android sqlite database so that it can be later compare easily.

Thanks alot for the concern.

Answer (score 1):

For your sqlite database, use a column that is of the type DATETIME

See this for more on DATETIME: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

You should also create an array of date objects so that you can do comparisons etc:

[Array of Dates in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801044/array-of-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

For the date selection you can use the DateSlider framework.

Fancy design and highly customizable:

http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/